# Flux: update array state

Tags: javascript, redux, vuex, flux

I have `itemById` in flux's state.

```
// state.js

{
  itemById: {},
}
```

And have two components `list1` `list2`. In these components, I get two different data `itemIds` via http to get items what I need, just like

```
// list1.js

{
  itemIds: [1, 3],
}

// list2.js
{
 itemIds: [1, 4],
}
```

When I update `item` what id is 1, `list1` and `list2` will update.

And now I want to add item to `list1` in other component.

```
// otherComponent.js

addItem(item) {
  store.addItem(item);
}
```

But this way can't update the `itemIds` in `list1`.

If move the `itemIds` data to state. When the listComponent destroy and recreat, `itemIds` is still exist, but I don't want this.

How should I design the flux state and component data to achieve this?